# nginx: read response header in njs subrequest

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to chain two requests together using nginx's njs module and subrequests.  I can see that `special_value` comes back in the response headers but I don't know how to read the value using `proxy_set_header`. The code below results in a blank value in `X-Special-Value`

nginx.conf:

```
location ~* /step_one {
  js_content njs_func;
}

location ~* /step_two {
  proxy_pass       http://some_other/api;
  proxy_set_header X-Special-Value      $http_special_val;
}
```

http.js

```
function njs_func(r) {
    r.headersOut['special_val'] = '42';
    r.subrequest('/step_two')
     .then(reply => r.return(reply.status, reply.responseBody));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

nginx.conf

```
set $specialValue "";

location ~* /step_one {
  js_content njs_func;
}

location ~* /step_two {
  proxy_pass       http://some_other/api;
  proxy_set_header X-Special-Value      $specialValue;
}
```

https.js

```
function njs_func(r) {
    r.variables.specialValue = '42';
    r.subrequest('/step_two')
     .then(reply => r.return(reply.status, reply.responseBody));
}
```